# SwiftUI - Updating values in a VStack

Tags: swiftui, state, vstack

Xcode 14.1, Ventura 13.1

I have a VStack with a load of graphical dials that I want to update.

[image: Dials]

For testing they are prepopulated with data from an array as follows:

```
struct Stats : Identifiable {
    var id : Int
    var title : String
    var currentData : CGFloat
    var goal : CGFloat
    var color : Color
    var unit: String
}

var stats_Data = [
    Stats(id: 0, title: "Daylight", currentData: 6.8, goal: 15, color: .yellow, unit: "Hrs"),
    Stats(id: 1, title: "Sunrise/Set", currentData: 3.5, goal: 5, color: .orange, unit: "Hour"),
    Stats(id: 2, title: "Cloud Cover", currentData: 585, goal: 1000, color: .gray, unit: "%"),
    Stats(id: 3, title: "Inclination", currentData: 6.2, goal: 10, color: .green, unit: "°"),
    Stats(id: 4, title: "Orientation", currentData: 12.5, goal: 25, color: .white, unit: "°"),
    Stats(id: 5, title: "Power", currentData: 16889, goal: 20000, color: .red, unit: "kW")
]
```

If I want to update any of this data, say "currentData" in a particular row how do I do this?

For text I can declare it as a @State var and then update it when a button is pressed, say. I have tried to do this in a similar fashion with a @State array but the preview/compiler doesn't like arrayed data within the VStack.

The test data is currently being passed in the VStack along the lines of:

```
ForEach(stats_Data){stat in
    VStack(spacing: 14){
...
    Circle()
        .trim(from: 0, to: (stat.currentData / stat.goal))
```

So how can I alter this to update data?

Comment: `stats_data` must be `@State` on the top level of the view and can only be updated by index e.g. `stats_data[1].currentData = 12.0` due to value semantics. An alternative is a view model.

Comment: Many thanks - I was getting my syntax wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Vadian's correct syntax answered this question, e.g. stats_data[1].currentData

Many thanks.